# How to call specific get method in web api using agluar ng-resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-resource

I have two or more get methods in web api, (as per below give code GetProducts and GetProductsNew are get methods). As i am using the ng-resource of angular js, whenever i try to call get function, it is giving an ambiguous error. Suppose i want to call GetProductsNew method then how can i call? Can anyone help please, thanks in advance :)

```
    // This is my web api code
    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
      ...
      public HttpResponseMessage GetProducts()
      { 
      }

      public HttpResponseMessage GetProductsNew()
      {
      }
    }

    // **This is my angular** 

    // This is the code in controller.js, using which i am calling the get method from above code, but here the problem is, since the above web api is having the two gt method, i am getting the "Multiple actions were found that match the request"

    productcatControllers.controller('ProductListCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    '$location', '$route', 'productService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $route, productService) 
    {
        productService.query(function (data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });
    }]);

   // This is the service of angular js
   var phonecatServices = angular.module('productcatServices', ['ngResource']);

   phonecatServices.factory("productService", function ($resource) {
       return $resource(
           "/api/Product/:id",
           { id: "@id" },
           {
              "update": { method: "PUT" }

           }
       );
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'ambiguous error' I'm guessing that you are getting :*"Multiple actions were found that match the request...."*? This is because you can not have multiple `Get` methods with the same signature in the same controller.

Try adding these attributes to the methods in your webapi

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route(Name = "GetProducts")]
  public HttpResponseMessage GetProducts()
  { 
  }

  [HttpGet]
  [Route(Name = "GetProductsNew")]
  public HttpResponseMessage GetProductsNew()
  {
  }
}
```

You need to install *AspNet.WebApi.WebHost* if you have not already done so:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

This article has a nice [explanation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) to attribute routing

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. I would like to know how to call specific get method from angular js controller. Since i am using ng-resource, i got predefined get, post, delete and remove. But i want to get any specific get method from angular js then how can i call?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Can't you simply call the different services like you would call any service using $http.get()? `$http.get('/GetProducts')` and `$http.get('/GetProductsNew')`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource
Can you please refer the above link?

The default set contains these actions:
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };

If we use resource object.get , save, delete. it will find the correct method in web api and it will execute. When web api controller has more than one get, post or delete, at that time it gives "Multiple actions were found that match the request"

Comment: Here you we need to register with Define Route, based on that it will execute the Get Method.

phonecatServices.factory("productService", function ($resource) {
       return $resource(
           "/api/GetProducts/:id",
           { id: "@id" },
           {
              "update": { method: "PUT" }

           }
       );
   });